# command line/tools (how) to convert RDF to OWL in python

Tags: python-2.7, owl

I have an ontology in RDF format and i will need to convert it into an owl format. what libraries are available for use in python? Thanks

Comment: 1. the search engine of your choice is broken? 2.) what means convert RDF format into OWL format? which format into which? 3.) you know the restrictions of StackOverflow regarding *"recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource"*?

Comment: I mean how to write out RDF/XML data into OWL/XML format

Comment: There is only owlready2 lib for OWL - but you already know this for sure. this is what Google returns as the first hit...if this doesn't work, there is nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

What's the distinction?  It's the same file with a different filename appended (.rdf vs .owl)?

Have you tried [RDF2RDF](http://www.l3s.de/~minack/rdf2rdf/)?  It's a jar, but that means it can be called from the command line---or within a python script.